# How to close a modal form from which I call a modal form

Tags: delphi, vcl

The main form opens a modal form B.
Form B opens a modal form C.

How can I close form B before form C opens?

Comment: When modal form C is about to be opened, close B with an option, so the main form can open modal form C.

Comment: To expand what LU RD is saying, don't open form C from form B, open it from form A. When you want to open Form C, close form B with a modal value that tells form A to open Form C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to postpone the call to *ShowModal* of FormC until FormB is closed. The following code can be placed inside a ButtonClick event handler. It makes use of the *ForceQueue* method available in recent Delphi versions. The *Anonymous Method* given to *ForceQueue* will be executed in the main thread at some later point. This allows the modal FormB to finish before FormC is shown.

```
  TThread.ForceQueue(nil,
    procedure
    var
      frm: TFormC;
    begin
      frm := TFormC.Create(Application);
      try
        frm.ShowModal;
      finally
        frm.Free;
      end;
    end
  );
  ModalResult := mrOK;
```